# Using Mongoid query syntax vs Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm having a little conundrum that I am confused by.

In rails console if I use

```
@o = ObjName.where(o_id: "VAL")
```

I don't get an object returned.  I get this though:

```
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:conditions=>{:site_id=>"PST"}},
  options:  {},
  class:    Site,
  embedded: false>
```

But if I use:

```
@o = ObjName.first(:conditions => {:o_id => "VAL"})
```

I do.  There where function is used within Mongoid, and my model includes Mongoid.  So I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: What is returned when you run the first command? `nil`?

Comment: I updated to show the actual message I receive.

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct syntax for [`where`](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where)

Comment: Oops, you are right... I updated the syntax but that doesn't work either.  None of the syntax examples on the mongoid.org page work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoid is very lazy in its loading. It will only execute the query and load the results into objects when you iterate over the results.

So Model.find will execute the mongodb findOne method and load into results.

```
@o = ObjName.where(o_id=>"VAL").first #will push into an object

@o = ObjName.where(:status=>"whoknows").all
#query has not been loaded
@o.each do |o|
  #now the query has been executed
  puts o
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need a ".all" at the end of your query.